# Problem with Fetching the data from Database

Tags: android, sqlite, ftp, cursor

I'm trying to fetch the details from Database for uploading the files from DDMS to ftp server. Normally, i can done this without using SQLiteDatabase.

But, now i need to upload the files using the ftp server `Host, Port, Username, Password` which are stored in Database. I've considered this Example to this [function.](http://pastebin.com/ntksM9Kt) I've this exception when using this method :

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

How can i Clear this error? And how can i pass the values from database to my FTP.

Comment: Include your database request code, so we have a chance to see what's going wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is the number of records in your database.
First query your request in database class 
and then in you activity
receive cursor 
as

```
Cursor c=db.data();
                (data is a method used for query and db is your object of database class)
c.moveToFirst();
while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
    //upload your database 
    c.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: yes, you're right. I missed the moveTo... Statements. It's working now. Thanks.